# How to compile Qt's MySQL driver for the iOS

Tags: ios, mysql, qt

I would like to know if anybody is able to compile the Qt's MySQL driver for the iOS?  I see a howto here:
http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7/sql-driver/

But I heard the driver needs to be compiled statically for the iOS.  Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently we need to use MariaDB to compile the driver:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/75215/how-to-compile-qt-s-mysql-driver-for-the-ios